# Image processing to get numbers from an image using cv2 and pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract the values from photographs of a Ritter biogas counter, specifically I want get the numbers at the black measurer. Here is an example:

[image]

I am trying to do this in Python, using the `cv2` and `pytesseract` libraries. Currently my script looks like this:

```
import argparse
import cv2
import pytesseract
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Parsing input arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Analyze an image from Ritter counter and extract the measured gas volume')
parser.add_argument("--img", required=True, help="Route to image to be analyzed")
args = parser.parse_args()
img=str(args.img)

# Reading photo as a grayscale image
img = cv2.imread(img, 0)
print("Pixels (height x width):")
print(img.shape[:2])

# Cropping image
img = img[377:420, 295:660]

#Transforming image to a binary image using a fixed threshold
for i in range(65,85,1):
   thresh = cv2.threshold(img, i, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)[1]
   data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
   plt.imshow(thresh)
   plt.title("Fixed: " + str(i) + "; Result: " + data)
   plt.show()
```

However, glare differences across the image, and those white lines of flash reflection in the counter's glass are causing me trouble to process the image before `pytesseract`. This is, currently, my best result:

[image]

I have tried using cv's adaptative thresholding with no better results. The expected result would process several images similar as the uploaded one, each with small differences in light reflection intensity and angle.

Comment: a polarization filter will remove reflections from the camera's view. that's a physical thing, not a digital thing.

Comment: I appreciate a lot your quick answer Chris. This is my first time working with computer vision, and since I lack any knowledge in photograph, I did not know if those reflections could be digitally removed. We will look for a polarization filter for the camera we use.

Comment: polarization filter will be a lot easier than trying to locate and subtract them in the image. --  for OCR I would generally recommend throwing tesseract away and using something that's actually State Of The Art. SOTA does not need nor want binarized input because binarization causes information loss. SOTA is anything that neither binarizes nor cuts the image into glyph components... before they've actually been detected by a neural network.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much Chris, I will take into account all of your suggestions.